# Can I use MOSFETS instead of transistor in the given circuit

Tags: power-supply, transistors, mosfet, ac, mains

I am modifying an electronic transformer as an irregular power supply as shown in the image below.

I am not able to find 13009 high power transistors.

Can I use two IRFP460N power MOSFETs in place of them?

Do I have to change anything else?

[image]

Comment: [MOSFET stands for "metal–oxide–semiconductor field-effect transistor."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET)  Your MOSFETs **are** transistors.  The ones you want to replace are [bipolar junction transistors (BJT.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is some kind of oscillating circuit, presumably to generate a higher frequency input to a smaller transformer than you could use at line frequency.

From the values given, I expect it makes use of the properties of the specified transistors to function properly.

I don't think you could replace them with just any other NPN transistor and expect it to work.

MOSFETs are right out.

Comment: I suspect it also uses the properties of the transformer.  It looks like one of those minimal component maximal cleverness designs that depends on everything being just so.

Comment: Yup.  Modify at risk of it never working again.

Answer (score 0):

As JRE says - it is highly device dependant.

This type of circuit usually works by switching when a decrease in drive or rate of change of switched current conducted current occurs.
There are two potentially interrelated mechanisms.

- Max transistor collector current = base drive current x beta (current gain).
  As collector current increases it reaches a point where Beta x Ib is less than Ic and the transistor starts to come out of saturation causing a switching event
- Core saturation causes a rapid increase in collector current and a loss of adequate base drive.

Or some mix of these.

MOSFET drive is dependent on gate voltage and NOT on available drive current so the first mechanism is not available.  Core saturation can still occur and how this affects the circuit would need to be looked at.

The R3 C3 D6 network is a preferential start circuit to turn Q2 on initially as otherwise the stable state is both transistors off.

A circuit like this would probably be easy to convert to MOSFETS by using a square wave oscillator to drive the two gates in antiphase. Sophistications like a small amount of non-overlap gate drive would not go astray :-).

.